# How to create nested dictionary from two lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
ramp_versions=['RAMPS_1_6','RAMPS_10','RAMPS_11','RAMPS_7','RAMPS_8_9']
columns=['Version','Date','Total_Ramps','Virtual_Ramps','Real_Ramps','Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements','Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable','Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999','Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999','Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD']
```

I want to create a nested dictionary where each ramp_version is a key and the values are a dictionary where each value in the columns is a key

So this is what I am after:

```
{'RAMPs_1_6': {'Version': "value",'Date': "value", 'Total_Ramps': "value", etc..},'RAMPS_10': {'Version': "value",'Date': "value", 'Total_Ramps': "value", etc..}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dict comprehension:

```
{ver: {col: "value" for col in columns} for ver in ramp_versions}
```

**Output:**

```
{'RAMPS_1_6': {'Version': 'value',
  'Date': 'value',
  'Total_Ramps': 'value',
  'Virtual_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD': 'value'},
 'RAMPS_10': {'Version': 'value',
  'Date': 'value',
  'Total_Ramps': 'value',
  'Virtual_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD': 'value'},
 'RAMPS_11': {'Version': 'value',
  'Date': 'value',
  'Total_Ramps': 'value',
  'Virtual_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD': 'value'},
 'RAMPS_7': {'Version': 'value',
  'Date': 'value',
  'Total_Ramps': 'value',
  'Virtual_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD': 'value'},
 'RAMPS_8_9': {'Version': 'value',
  'Date': 'value',
  'Total_Ramps': 'value',
  'Virtual_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999': 'value',
  'Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD': 'value'}}
```

Comment: alrighty that did it...I did not know you can do list comprehension in another list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```
nest = {}
for r in ramp_versions:
   nest[r] = dict(zip(columns, ['val' for x in columns]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a loop for keys and set values for that in an empty defined dictionary

see the following example:

```
ramp_versions=['RAMPS_1_6','RAMPS_10','RAMPS_11','RAMPS_7','RAMPS_8_9']
columns=['Version','Date','Total_Ramps','Virtual_Ramps','Real_Ramps','Real_Ramps_With_All_Measurements','Real_Ramps_Unsurveyable','Real_Ramps_Partial_With_999','Real_Ramps_Partial_WO_999','Real_Ramps_Partial_W_RAMP_WIDTH_<36_or_DWS_BAD']

my_dict = {}

i=0
for ramp in ramp_versions:
    my_dict[ramp] = columns[i]
    i+=1

print(my_dict)
# print(my_dict.keys())
# print(my_dict.values())
```