# Creating nested dictionary from two lists one of which contains dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928099/how-to-create-nested-dictionary-from-two-lists) but with an added caveat.

I have two lists identical in length. One contains my keys, and the other contains a list of dictionaries belonging to said keys. Example below (yes the Nones are intentional)

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2, 'key3']
vals = [[{'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'}], [{'subkey1: 'val2'},None],[{'subkey1':'val3'}, {'subkey3':'val1}, None, None]]
```

What I'd like to do is match each *dictionary* in each list to a key to create a nested dict.

So something like below:

```
final = {'key1':{'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'}, 'key2':{'subkey1': 'val2'}, 'key3':{'subkey1':'val3'}, {'subkey3':'val1'}}
```

I know we can use dictionary comprehension to do this. I created a dictionary of empty dicts.

```
s = {}
for i in keys:
    for v in vals:
        s[i] = {}
        break
```

Then I wrote the following to iterate through the list of dicts I'd like to pair up accounting for the non dictionary values in my list.

```
x = 0
while x < len(keys):
    for i in keys:
        for element in vals[x]:
            if isinstance(element, dict) == True:
                s[str(i)].append(element)
            else:
                print('no')
    x=x+1
```

However when I run this, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

How can I append to a dictionary using this for loop?

Comment: can't use append on a dict

Comment: Your `final` dictionary is not valid. Specifically, for `key3`: `'key3':{'subkey1':'val3'}, {'subkey3':'val1'}`. Was the value supposed to be a list instead?

Comment: "the other contains a list of dictionaries belonging to said keys". Actually, it doesn't. The other is a list of lists with dictionaries. Both your starting lists have syntax errors. It's worth taking the time to make sure your code examples are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the less readable dictionary comprehension solution

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
vals = [
  [{'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'}],
  [{'subkey1': 'val2'}, None],
  [{'subkey1': 'val3'}, {'subkey3':'val1'}, None, None]
]

s = {
    k: {
        sk: sv for d in (x for x in v if x is not None) for sk, sv in d.items()
    } for k, v in zip(keys, vals)
}
```

Gives

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'},
 'key2': {'subkey1': 'val2'},
 'key3': {'subkey1': 'val3', 'subkey3': 'val1'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done fairly easily using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
vals = [
  [{'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'}],
  [{'subkey1': 'val2'},None],
  [{'subkey1':'val3'}, {'subkey3':'val1'}, None, None]
]

final = defaultdict(dict)

for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    for d in vals[idx]:
        if d is not None:
            final[key].update(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {
 'key1': {'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'},
 'key2': {'subkey1': 'val2'},
 'key3': {'subkey1': 'val3', 'subkey3': 'val1'}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

can't use append on a dict
try this maybe?

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
vals = [[{'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'}], [{'subkey1': 'val2'},None],[{'subkey1':'val3'}, {'subkey3':'val1'}, None, None]]
s = {}
for i in keys:
    s[i] = {}
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    for element in vals[i]:
        if isinstance(element, dict) == True:
            s[str(key)].update(element)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'subkey1': 'val1', 'subkey2': 'val2'}, 'key2': {'subkey1': 'val2'}, 'key3': {'subkey1': 'val3', 'subkey3': 'val1'}}
```

Comment: You should test your answer before posting - It doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: yeah, ngl i just realised that and i'm working on fixing it